# Sql query in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am using the following query to update record in asp.net, what's wrong with it?

```
Dim updateSqlString As String = "UPDATE Subscriber_Communication SET([[marketing_rec_id]=?, [Currently_own]=?,[Purchase_date]=?, [Interested_in_owning]=?, [Product_of_interest]=?," & _
"[Time_frame_to_own]=?, [Referred_by]=?, [Campaign_Code]=?,[Last_Update]=?, [record_created_on]=?, [Comments]=?, [Comment_Date]=?, [Community_id]=?," & _
"[Certification]=?, [subscriber_Type]=?, [unsubscribe_comment]=?" & _
"WHERE [Communication_id]=" & Communication_id
  Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(insertSqlString, conn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("marketing_rec_id", marketing_rec_id)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Currently_own", Currently_own)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Purchase_date", Purchase_date)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Interested_in_owning", Interested_in_owning)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Product_of_interest", Product_of_interest)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time_frame_to_own", Time_frame_to_own)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Referred_by", Referred_by)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Campaign_Code", Campaign_Code)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Last_Update", Last_Update)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("record_created_on", record_created_on)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Comments", Comments)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Comment_Date", Comment_Date)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Community_id", Community_id)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Certification", Certification)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("subscriber_Type", subscriber_Type)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("unsubscribe_comment", unsubscribe_comment)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? Does it fail? Doesn't it update the record? Anything else?

Comment: it never updates, is the syntax correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
Dim updateSqlString As String = 
    "UPDATE Subscriber_Communication SET [marketing_rec_id]=@marketing_rec_id, [Currently_own]=@Currently_own,   ..." etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the string variable as

> updateSqlString

while you are using

> insertSqlString

to update the database .